# Chrome's netlogs shwoing "is_preconnect=false" for resource request even after using "preconnect" resource hint for that resource

Tags: google-chrome, http, ssl, web-performance, preconnect

I am using the "preconnect" resource hints in my site for the font's api as

```
<link rel="preconnect" crossorigin href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
```

However when i am checking waterfall analysis in chrome devtools, the DNS lookup and SSL connections for `https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxKKTU1Kg.woff2` at the time of fetching.

When I checked the netlogs in netlog-viewer.appspot.com, the `HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER` gives me this result:

```
https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxKKTU1Kg.woff2
Start Time: 2020-02-18 12:14:04.660

t=9003 [st=  0] +HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER  [dt=123]
                 --> is_preconnect = false
                 --> url = "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxKKTU1Kg.woff2"
t=9003 [st=  0]    HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER_BOUND
                   --> source_dependency = 3231 (URL_REQUEST)
t=9003 [st=  0]   +PROXY_RESOLUTION_SERVICE  [dt=0]
t=9003 [st=  0]      PROXY_RESOLUTION_SERVICE_RESOLVED_PROXY_LIST
                     --> pac_string = "DIRECT"
t=9003 [st=  0]   -PROXY_RESOLUTION_SERVICE
t=9003 [st=  0]    HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER_PROXY_SERVER_RESOLVED
                   --> proxy_server = "DIRECT"
t=9003 [st=  0]    HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_STARTED_JOB
                   --> source_dependency = 3234 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=9126 [st=123] -HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER
```

Why is it showing `is_preconnect` false?